# expo error installing or running app

Tags: react-native, simulator, expo

when I try to run my app on the iOS simulator I get the error :

Error running `xcrun simctl openurl booted exp://localhost:19000`: An error was              encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=60):
 The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out
 Operation timed out

Error installing or running app. Error: Process exited with non-zero code: 60

any idea how to solve this error ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This usually is an error with the Simulator. If you remove `expo` (delete the app) from the simulator and run the command again, it should build fine.

However, if it still fails, `Erasing all content and settings` on the simulator does the trick too.

Comment: You can also run `xcrun simctl erase all` as a handy shortcut to erase all the simulator devices.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work for me. Still searching for a solution. One difference, I'm not using expo.

Answer (score 14):

It may be an issue with some outdated simulators in your simulator cache. On MacOS remove the sub-directories in the following directory:

`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/`

Comment: Thanks kojow7, this is the fix I needed!

Answer (score 4):

Start the Simulator separately with the following command: `open -a Simulator`
After this if you run `expo start` again and type `i` the Simulator will boot up properly.

Answer (score 2):

**FOUNT IT!**

you must have a .watchmanconfig file (*like below*)

[File example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36A0Z.png)

When you initialize a project with `expo init "projectname"`, there is no **.watchmanconfig** file.

So, create one and in this file, just initialize an empty object like this : {}

Then you can start with `expo start` or `yarn/npm start`

It solved all my problem.

Hope it does for you too.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone like me also searching this issue, it is possible to un-eject your app and run again like normal. From the docs, Delete the ios and android directories from your project. Delete the isDetached and detach keys from your project's app.json. You can now use your project like a normal Expo project (with no ExpoKit). Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/advanced-expokit-topics/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to boot the simulator and the option for Reset Content and Settings is greyed out, You can try this

Mac --- > System Settings --- > Storage --- > Developer --- > Delete Xcode Caches.

Restart the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have **.watchmanconfig** file present in root, if not create one **.watchmanconfig** and initialize empty object and run command **npm start** again

Answer (score 0):

Switching to `Node 18.13.0`, previously `Node 21.5.0`, and building again solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

i solved by

> Blockquote

Reset Content and Settings

> Blockquote

in the Simulator. Similar to #67 in this regard. then later close the stimulator and terminal. to avoid future issues like

> Blockquote

FetchError: network timeout for API calls

> Blockquote.